# Reading multiple Cvs files sequentially(open,close,high,low) and calculating Moving Average Convergence Divergence

Tags: java

Please i need help to read through a CVSfile sequentially and calculating the MACD. what i have is not working, i will appreciate any correction.
**REQUIREMENT**

"provides a convenient means of downloading an investment's history consisting of the following fields: Ticker, Date, Open, High, Low, Close, and Volume.

Download a year's history for each of the following investments into separate .csv files: 
F Ford
IPG Interpublic
Grp Cos 
RTN Raytheon Co 
SYMC Symantec Corp 
TWX Time Warner TJX 
TJX Companies VSH 
Vishay Intertechnolog...
 IBM International Business Machines.
 Reading each file sequentially, use string split or the tokenizer with a comma as a delimiter to parse each of the .csv files into fields. Use each investment's history fields to determine the Moving Average Convergence Divergence (MACD) for each of the investments as of 4/1/2016 per"

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.FileReader;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;



public class invest // class name and identifier

{

// main method begins execution of Java application

// this method will not return information

public static void main(String[] args) 

{

try

        {                  

// csv file containing data

    String ford = "/Users/ajibadeadedapo/Documents/investmentCV/f.csv";
    String interpublic = "/Users/Documents/investmentCV/ipg.csv";
    String raytheon = "/Users/Documents/investmentCV/rtn.csv";
    String symantec = "/Users/Documents/investmentCV/symc.csv";
    String timeWarner = "/Users/ajibadeadedapo/Documents/investmentCV/twx.csv";
    String tjxComp = "/Users/Documents/investmentCV/tjx.csv";
    String vishay = "/Users/Documents/investmentCV/vsh.csv";
    String interBusiness = "/Users/ajibadeadedapo/Documents/investmentCV/ibm.csv";



            // create BufferedReader to read csv file

            BufferedReader bufferedFord = 

            new BufferedReader( new FileReader(ford));

            BufferedReader bufferedInterpublic  = 

            new BufferedReader( new FileReader(interpublic));

            BufferedReader bufferedRaytheon  = 

            new BufferedReader( new FileReader(raytheon));

            BufferedReader bufferedSymantec  = 

            new BufferedReader( new FileReader(symantec));

            BufferedReader bufferedTimeWarner  = 

            new BufferedReader( new FileReader(timeWarner));

            BufferedReader bufferedTjxComp  = 

            new BufferedReader( new FileReader(tjxComp));

            BufferedReader bufferedVishay  = 

            new BufferedReader( new FileReader(vishay));

            BufferedReader bufferedInterBusiness  = 

            new BufferedReader( new FileReader(interBusiness));



            String stringLine = "";

            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = null;

            int lineNumber = 0, tokenNumber = 0;



            System.out.println("Ford History (Token #1-Date, Token "

            + "#2-Open, Token #3-High, Token #4-Low, Token "

            + "#5-Close, Token #6-Volume, Token #7-12 Day EMA, "

            + "Token #8-26 Day EMA, Token #9-MACD):");




            // read comma separated file line by line

            while((stringLine = bufferedFord.readLine()) != null)

            {

            lineNumber++;

            if(lineNumber == 254) // read only this line

            {            

            // break comma separated line using ","

            stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer

            (stringLine, ",");



            while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())

            {

            // display csv values

            tokenNumber++;

            {

            System.out.println("Line # " + 

            lineNumber + ", Token # " + tokenNumber

                            + ", Token : " + 

            stringTokenizer.nextToken());

            }



            }

            }               

                // reset token number

                tokenNumber = 0;

            }
```

Comment: I am not getting any output...... it gives me an en error whenever i run it. Maybe i am doing something wrong.

Comment: while((stringLine = bufferedFord.readLine()) != null)

            {

            lineNumber++;

            if(lineNumber == 254) // read only this line

            {            

            // break comma separated line using ","

            stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer

            (stringLine, ",");

Comment: having a stacktrace where?

Comment: If you don't have a stacktrace then maybe you don't have 254 lines in your CSV file?

Comment: i dont have it ......i have punch of data about open, close and blah blah.... the 254 in the code is the pattern  to calculate MACD

Comment: Well, that's not what I'm seeing, so I think you need a tutor or something more focused than stackoverflow can give you.